# What tools are there to factor multivariate polynomials over a field of characteristic 2

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

I would like to factor a multivariate polynomials over a field of characteristic 2. It is not that large (tens of variables and hundreds of terms).

I tried Mathematica and Pari-GP, and googled around for open source options.

Comment: And does it work? One can also consider the polynomial only in one variable, and the other variables as parameters. Then the Berlekamp algorithm does it.

Comment: www.sagemath.org, for instance

    sage: import random
    sage: R = PolynomialRing(GF(2), names=','.join(['x%s'%k for k in [1..9]]))
    sage: R.gens()
    (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9)
    sage: f = sum( [g^random.choice([2,4,6,8]) for g in R.gens()] )
    sage: f.factor()
    (x1^4 + x9^4 + x2^3 + x3^3 + x8^3 + x7^2 + x4 + x5 + x6)^2
    sage: